# Add Build Description in Sectioned View using DSL/Groovy Jenkins plugin

Tags: jenkins-job-dsl

I wish to use jenkins-job-dsl plugin to add 'Build Description' column in my sectioned view. Unfortunately I couldn't find any information in Jenkins Job DSL API (http://sheehan.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#) about it.

[image]

I assume it is not available via dsl jenkins api, but I would like to make sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If something is supported out of the box, you can use a [Configure Block](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/The-Configure-Block) to add any config elements:

```
sectionedView('project-summary') {
  filterBuildQueue()
  filterExecutors()
  sections {
    listView {
      name('Project A')
      jobs {
        regex(/project-A-.*/)
      }
      columns {
        status()
        weather()
        name()
        lastSuccess()
        lastFailure()
      }       
    }
  }
  configure { view ->
    view / sections / 'hudson.plugins.sectioned__view.ListViewSection' / columns << 'jenkins.plugins.extracolumns.BuildDescriptionColumn' {
      columnWidth(80)
      forceWidth(false)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank for Your help! But for someone Who is looking to add 'Build Description' into existed view will be easier to use in this way: buildDescriptionColumn {
                        columnWidth(80)
                        forceWidth(false)
}

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer of daspilker semi-usefull. The way to go is still the configure block. But anno 2019 it doesn't work quite correctly anymore. This worked for me:

```
 columns {
    status()
    name()
    weather()
    lastSuccess()
    lastFailure()
    lastDuration()
  }

  configure {
    view ->
      view / columns << 'jenkins.branch.DescriptionColumn' {
        columnWidth(80)
        forceWidth(false)
      }
  }
```

The part "jenkins.branch.DescriptionColumn" is copy pasted straight out of the config.xml for the listView. Which looked like:

```
<listView>
      <owner class="hudson" reference="../../.."/>
      <name>test</name>
      <filterExecutors>false</filterExecutors>
      <filterQueue>false</filterQueue>
      <properties class="hudson.model.View$PropertyList"/>
      <jobNames>
        <comparator class="hudson.util.CaseInsensitiveComparator"/>
        <string>something</string>
      </jobNames>
      <jobFilters/>
      <columns>
        <hudson.views.StatusColumn/>
        <hudson.views.WeatherColumn/>
        <hudson.views.JobColumn/>
        <hudson.views.LastSuccessColumn/>
        <hudson.views.LastFailureColumn/>
        <hudson.views.LastDurationColumn/>
        <hudson.views.BuildButtonColumn/>
        <hudson.plugins.favorite.column.FavoriteColumn plugin="favorite@2.3.1"/>
        <jenkins.branch.DescriptionColumn plugin="branch-api@2.0.20"/>
      </columns>
      <recurse>false</recurse>
    </listView>
```